# Given $x^2+xy+y^2=0$

Tags: polynomials

> Given $x,y\neq 0$ such that $x^2+xy+y^2=0$. Evaluate the following, $$\left(\frac{x}{x+y}\right)^{2013}+\left(\frac{y}{x+y}\right)^{2013}$$

I have tried to merge the fraction, factorize the numerator and simplify the fraction, but I don't know when to use the initial equation. Any ideas or solution would be helpful.